# How to receive the changes from nested firestore collections into a single flutter stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For example when we need to read the changes in all cities (a subcollection under the country collection) using the following path:

Countries/{country_id}/cities/{city_id}
For each country_id we need a separate stream. How to receive changes in cities in a single stream for all countries?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).  On Flutter, you will want to use the [collectionGroup()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore/collectionGroup.html) method to create that query.

```
firestore.collectionGroup("cities")
```